# Jquery drop down working ok... but could be better

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, bind, mouseenter, mouseleave

here's my working drop down menu...

http://jsfiddle.net/NAyWQ/7/

it does the job, and it's pretty much all the functionality I need at the moment... however I feel like it could be optimized a bit. namely, is there a way I can do this without the boundary div? also, the drop down re-fires if I go back up into the menu, not a big deal, but it would be nice to prevent this behavior.

any suggestions/tweaks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: wow, cool. I didn't know about codereview. I'll post there and see what happens. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Working off of @AndrewMilson's example, you can do this:

```
$("#press, #contact, #about").hover(function(){
    $("#dd_" + this.id).slideDown("fast");
}, function(){
    $("#dd_" + this.id).slideUp("fast");
});
```

Here it is in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NAyWQ/11/

Comment: thanks joseph! ahh yes, I had considered just using the hover function at first, but if you look at my original code, I need the drop down's to stay put while the mouse is over them... thus I have to bind mouseenter/mouseleave. I think that was my logic.

if you can see a way to use hover and keep this happening that would be grand. again, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/NAyWQ/11/.

**here is the jquery** it uses no boundry div.

```
$("#press, #contact, #about").hover(function(){
    $("#dd_" + this.id).slideDown("fast");
}, function(){
    $("#dd_" + this.id).slideUp("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle you have is a little messy and not very expandable. I would suggest using "ul" instead of "div"s because its cleaner and you can do more things with CSS. Also, I would refrain from using too many IDs as this means you have to always manually update them.

Here is an example I put together. This method also has support for nested dropdowns (if you wanted them).

http://jsfiddle.net/EYv9g/4/

You'll see ">" in the CSS. This is a really powerful selector that allows you to apply styles to an element that is a direct child of the parent, but not elements farther down

For example:

```
ul.menu > li {background: yellow}
```

would apply to...

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>me
        <ul>
            <li>but NOT me</li>
        </ul>
    <li><a>me</a>
<ul>
```